# Data binding not working with Capital Letter package name

Tags: java, android, kotlin, 2-way-object-databinding, package-name

I have a Android project who's package name is kind of like this `com.example.MyPackag`e where as `MyPackage` has two capital letters `M` and `P`, Due to them i am not able to use data binding.

When i add data binding and build my project it says not able to guess the name. I found out on stackover flow there are people discussing that it is because you have capital case letters inside package name.

Comment: Please add detail about the problem. Also avoid to add not useful details

Comment: tell us what is the error and your log.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the package name of your code, just don't change/update the **application_id** from build.gradle file

PlayStore uses **application_id** from app-level build.gradle file as identifier

Comment: Your answer is correct but will i be able to use data binding by changing package name?

Comment: [kapt] An exception occurred: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: couldn't make a guess for com.example.MyPackage.databinding.ActivityLoginBindingSw600dpImpl this is the issue i get even after changing the package name to com.example.mypackage it still gives this error

Comment: `com.example.MyPackage` ? if you change the package name to `com.example.mypackage`, then it should have automatically changed databinding variables.
Try to clean and rebuild the project. also make sure you aren't mixing source **package name** with **application_id**

Comment: Yes it is working great now.Issue is that i had to change the package name in manifest as well. Due to some reason refactor process didn't work to change the package name in manifest as well, So i had to change it in the manifest and after that invalidate cache and restart the android studio made it work perfectly !